# After importing audio into unity, the file is playing back slightly slower and at a slightly lower pitch

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, sample-rate

I have tried converting the audio file prior to importing into unity to both 44.1k and 48k sample rates and they sounds identical when played back in unity (slowed down and pitched down). I have tried this with a .wav file and a .aif at both sample rates mentioned above and it sounds the same. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I am not clear what exactly is being played, how it is being played and the aural result. Could you spell this out more explicitly? Expected result: if the same PCM data is given formats of 44.1k and 48k sample rates, the 48k rate will play back slightly quicker and will sound pitched up, relative to the 44.1k rate playback.